# I can't install anything on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql, dependencies, 20.10

When I try

```
$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

I have this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.22- 
0ubuntu0.20.10.2) but 8.0.23- 
0ubuntu0.20.10.1 is to be installed
synaptic : Depends: libept1.6.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages 
(or specify a solution).
```

Then I try:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

I have this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
linux-headers-5.8.0-38 linux-headers-5.8.0-38-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
mysql-server-8.0
Suggested packages:
mailx tinyca
The following packages will be upgraded:
mysql-server-8.0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,324 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/main amd64 mysql-server-8.0 amd64 
8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 [1,324 kB]
Fetched 1,324 kB in 7s (184 kB/s)                                              
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 251399 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.10.1_amd64.deb ...
grep: /etc/mysql/: No such file or directory
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23- 
0ubuntu0.20.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
new mysql-server-8.0 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23- 
0ubuntu0.20.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I try this code:

```
$sudo apt update
```

outpt is:

```
[sudo] password for sara: 
Hit:1 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease           
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease [110 
kB]     
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                    
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com groovy InRelease     
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Fetched 110 kB in 6s (17.9 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
51 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

I searched a lot, but didn't find a good solution. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: Did you try `siudo apt --fix-broken install` as suggested in the error text ?

Comment: @Soren A   Yes, I try the fix broken code, and I have an error that I show the result in my question.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear that there's a MySQL installation that's present and will not respond to being shut down. Do you have backups of the MySQL databases? If so, you could do a brute-force removal of MySQL, then install the new version, then restore your databases.

Comment: I see `sudo apt install` but not `sudo apt --fix-broken install`...
In the output there are an MYSQL error, did you fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered similar issue recently and in my case mysql service link appears broken. Follow these steps:

- Check for any broken service link (`/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service` )
- Remove any MariaDB stuff (`sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep maria`)
- Details found [here](https://blog.kesavan.info/2024/03/03/fix-for-mysql-8x-installation-failure-on-ubuntu-20-04/)